# Eager loading without empty collections

Tags: laravel-4, eloquent

```
$products = Product::with(
    array(
        'productDescriptions' => function($query) {
             $query->lang(App::getLocale());
         },
        'productImages' => function($query) {
             $query->imageType('thumbnail');    
        }))
    ->paginate($items_per_page);
```

Hi, is there an easy way to eager load relationships but only if they exists? More specifically I would like to get only these products, if their productDescriptions are not empty.
In SQL I would simply do a inner join, but how to do it an easy way in Eloquent? I could foreach over all returned products and check if `$product->productDescription->count() > 0` but maybe there is simpler way to achieve that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are 2 methods for this: `has` and `whereHas`:

```
$products = Product::with(   // this part will load the relation
  array(
    'productDescriptions' => function($query) {
         $query->lang(App::getLocale());
     },
    'productImages' => function($query) {
         $query->imageType('thumbnail');    
    }))
  ->has('productDescriptions') // this will make sure only Products having related descriptions will be fetched
  ->paginate($items_per_page);
```

Comment: I've read about it in documentation and it "should" work, but unfortunetly it doesn't - I've checked it with `dd($products->getCollection()->first()->productDescriptions);` and it returns `object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection)#331 (1) { ["items":protected]=> array(0) { } }`

Comment: This actually works, but only when I rewrite the same constrain as in eager loading.

`->has('productDescriptions', '>=', 1, 'and', function($query) {
     $query->where('lang_id', '=', App::getLocale());
    })`

Comment: Yes, you asked for non-empty `productDescriptions`, but if you need to limit them like in eager loading, you can do what you have done, or there is shorter `whereHas` method for that: `whereHas('productDescriptions', function($q)...`

Answer (score 0):

You can do [Eager Load Constraints](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#eager-loading) as seen in the docs.

So you would need to do something LIKE this (not tested - but you get the idea):

```
$products = Product::with(
    array(
        'productDescriptions' => function($query) {
             $query->where('productDescription', '!=', '')->lang(App::getLocale());
         },
        'productImages' => function($query) {
             $query->imageType('thumbnail');    
        }))
    ->paginate($items_per_page);
```